# Installation of Nvidia Driver on other Azure VMs type

Tags: python, azure, virtual-machine, nvidia, azure-virtual-machine

Is it possible to install Nvidia driver on other types of Azure VMs apart from the N-series?? If so please someone should provide instructions to do so.

I tried following instructions on different Microsoft link on how to install it but none worked. I downloaded different Nvidia drivers from Microsoft link.

My Azure VM is 16GB RAM, Windows 10 and also the basic Azure VMs type.

I'm trying to install the Nvidia driver on the Azure VM for a AI python project that requires it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPU optimized VM sizes are specialized virtual machines available with single, multiple, or fractional GPUs. These sizes are designed for compute-intensive, graphics-intensive, and visualization workloads. In Azure, the **N-Series VMs** are the GPU optimized series, no other series at them moment have Nvidia hardware.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes-gpu

Comment: Thank you for replying. I guess I will have to look into Google colab.